# Does jquery select2 plugin support the ability to have alternative row colors in the dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, colors, jquery-select2, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown list and I am using the [Select2 jquery plugon](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) which works great.

One thing i ran into is a use case where each of the items is very long so the text wraps to 3 or 4 lines.  I wanted to see if you can style the dropdowns to have alternative row color to make it easier to see where one item ends and another begins when you are scrolling down the list of items.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, in fact it's quite easy, this is how you do it:

In your css stylesheet create a class for the items that you want to display in a different color, for instance:

```
.oddRow {background-color:#CCC;}
```

Then add that class to the `option` elements that you want to be displayed in a different color before the call to `select2`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#source optgroup option:odd").addClass('oddRow');
  $("#source").select2();
});
```

See a working example in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kprDSqbobXhjOpyuLgXT?p=preview) or in the embed snippet bellow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#source optgroup option:odd").addClass('oddRow');
  $("#source").select2();
});
```

```css
.oddRow {background-color:#CCC;}
```

```html
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="select2@*" data-semver="3.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css" />
    <script data-require="select2@*" data-semver="3.5.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width:300px" id="source">
      <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Central Time Zone">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: @leora Could you please let me know if this answers your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this just by adding two css classes in your css file, or at the top of the file that contain the select field.

Add the following:

```
.select2-results li:nth-child(2n+1){
    background-color:red;
}
```

Where `select2-results` is an outer class of `ul` tag. So please change it if your are using some different class.